# PHP Recursive Function to get Folders and Files from DB

Tags: php, recursion, mysqli

I am trying to convert a mysql table to a POO array using a recursive function to get all directories and push them inside each directory. However I am having some implementation problems since my code is not working (only half of it). I have edited some code because it's very long (for a stackoverflow post) so if something is missing warn me.

**Example Folders Table:**

```
id | parent_id | foldername
1  | 0         | folder1
2  | 0         | folder2
3  | 1         | folder3
4  | 2         | folder4
5  | 3         | folder5
```

**Example Files Table:**

```
id | folderid | filename | filepath
 1 | 1        | file1    | serverpath
 2 | 1        | file2    | serverpath
 3 | 2        | file3    | serverpath
 4 | 5        | file4    | serverpath
 5 | 4        | file5    | serverpath
```

folderid references id from Folders table

Example Filesystem Image:
[image: Filesystem Image]

**My PHP Classes:**

```
class Root
{
    public $root = array();

    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->root = $object;
    }
}

class Folder
{
    public $folderid;
    public $foldername;
    public $files = array();
    public $folders = array();

    public function __construct($folderid, $foldername)
    {
        $this->folderid = $folderid;
        $this->foldername = $foldername;
    }

    public function addFile($file)
    {
        if ($file instanceof File) {
            $this->files[] = $file;
        }
    }

    public function addFolder($folder)
    {
        if ($folder instanceof Folder) {
            $this->folders[]=$folder;
        }
    }
}

class File
{
    public $filename;
    public $filepath;

    public function __construct($filename, $filepath)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->filepath = $filepath;
    }
}
```

PHP code (GetFileSystem.php):

```
<?php
$config = require_once('config.php');

function getRootContent()
{
    $root = array();
    $conn = new mysqli($config->host, $config->user, $config->password, $config->db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Connection failed:' . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,foldername FROM foldertable WHERE parent_id=? AND published=1')) {
        //I only want to get specific folders so there for each id (folderid)) 
        foreach ($config->parentid as $id) {
            $root[] = getSubFolders($stmt, $id);
        }
    } else {
        die('Query/Statement Error:' . $conn->error);
    }
}

function getSubFolders($stmt, $id)
{
    $stmt->reset();
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($folderid, $foldername);

    $data = array();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $data[] = new Folder($folderid, $foldername);
            //TO DO $data[] = new File();
        }

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $row[$folderid] = getSubFolders($stmt, $row['folderid']);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

    $root = new Root(getRootContent());

    var_dump($root);
```

I am trying to convert my java code to php so some things might be bad coded (I am not a php expert so any help would be good).

Comment: Near the bottom, where is the variable $tableid coming from? $row[$tableid]

Comment: @waterloomatt in my java code I had tableid, forgot to switch there, thanks for noticing.